# How get element which was generate dynamically?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I need to get access to element which was generate dynamically in jQuery.

Thing which I want make is hide first and last elements which are generated by `kendoUI grid` element.

```
$(".myItem").first().hide();
$(".myItem").last().hide();
```

So I know if I have some event for example `click` on generated element I can use `.on()` or `.live()`. But I don't have any event in this case.

How can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hiya, if you will access an element obviously you will attach an event to it right? else what is the point? please let me know, just keen man `:)` Also see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145397/how-to-access-jquery-dynamically-generted-elements

Comment: No, I only need to get access to it I don't make any events.

Comment: is there a sample page or snippet of generated html you could post? we could make a working jsfiddle or something then...

Comment: @MateuszRogulski aha okies `:)` thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a known structure then you can get the nearest thing with an ID and work your way to it. Methods like `parent()`, `nearest()`, and `children()` will let you move your way over to the main grid container div and then you can use the `:first` and `:last` pseudo elements.

You can use the databound event as outlined here to hook into it after the rows have been created:

- http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/events.aspx

Example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataBound: function(e) {
         // use jquery as outlined above to find required elements
     }
 });
```

Comment: The technique itself should work, you just need to find an event to hook in to it after the dom elements are created.

Comment: So I ask for this not for way to do it without dynamically generated.

Comment: Have you tried hooking into the dataBound event? http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/events.aspx

Comment: This is what I'm looking for :) Thanks, if you would edit your post and add `dataBound` solution to it. I think it can be helpful for someone ;)